# custom module - can't remove field from a page

Tags: views

We have an interactive Drupal 7 website in which the user enters data in forms for a report.  I'm trying to have two fields on two separate pages no longer be visible to the user. I go to Structure>Content Types>Select the appropriate content>Manage Display>Select Hidden for the appropriate field.  We don't want to delete the field, as we have data in that field which we may want to access in the future regarding past reports.  This hiding of the field has NO affect.  The hidden fields on either Content Type are still visible and accessible.  I have tried finding the occurrence of the machine name of the field in the code and commenting it out.  Nothing works, and when I comment out the handlers it breaks the website and it is no longer accessible until I uncomment the code.

I have found nothing in the logs which seem useful to me.

I admit I have very little experience behind the scenes either creating or delving into the code, and have no idea what to do next.

Can someone please help guide me in the correct direction to work through this and to make these fields not visible to the users?  Thanks in advance!